# Copying a worksheet from one workbook to another

Tags: python, openxml, xlsx

My application generates Office Open XML spreadsheets, and I have a preformatted cover page that I want to copy verbatim into each workbook with formatting intact. How can I do this? My app is in Python but I'll use external programs if I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/) does what you want.

Comment: Gave it a try. It _almost_ works, but seems to have a bug that prevents it from copying indentation properly. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @Taymon Well there are 2 python libraries for working with excel files which are more popular than others, I read somewhere that one works only with xls files and one (openpyxl) with xlsx files. I would say if someone wants to find out which one is better he should try some libraries and then decide which one stick to. but it is a bit tiresome.

Comment: How do you copy sheets between workbooks in openpyxl? Documentation says it has to be within the same workbook? http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.worksheet.copier.html?highlight=copy_worksheet